# Mini-DIN to USB-Power

Tags: power-supply, usb, connector

I have an old laser printer, [HP LaserJet 2100](http://www.andovercg.com/datasheets/hp-laserjet-2100-series.pdf), with 2 ports:

- a parallel port;
- [an 8-pin mini-DIN female "LocalTalk port" connector](http://connector.pinouts.ru/8_pin_mini-DIN_female/):

[image]

I am using a Raspberry Pi as a network print server. The Pi is connected to the parallel port via a USB-to-Parallel cable. Raspberry Pi is powered by a micro-USB connector and cable.

I was thinking of finding or making a DIN8-to-Micro-USB power-only cable.

Does the extra DIN8 port supply (enough) power that can be used to power the Pi?
If so, what would the correct pinout be?

Comment: How the Hull should we know?!  You haven't told us what the printer is, what the function of the port is, whether it even has any power connections in it, nothing!

Comment: At a guess, it looks like Appletalk. Other than that, back to Majenko!

Comment: @Majenko: Sorry. I had (naively) assumed that this is a standard data port so the printer model is not important. I'll update the question.

Comment: @carveone It might be, or it might be a custom port for adding extra paper trays or something. Who knows?

Comment: @Majenko Er. Good point. I'm wildly guessing for the fun of it :-)

Comment: There is no power in a LocalTalk connector, so the answer to your question is NO. You can't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume it's Appletalk or Localtalk. I think that's a safe bet given that's it is a)old b)laser and c)8 pin din.

In all cases, only ground is available. Which is the same as most other serial port connection systems, USB aside.

Edit: Confirmed (after my browser crashed on that PDF!). That's a [LocalTalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LocalTalk) port. They come in various levels (more functions on the pins) but none of them carry power I'm afraid. See http://www.interfacebus.com/Apple_MiniDIN_PinOut.html